# How to plot the slope of each individual segment of a line chart (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a medium-sized dataset (soil moisture vs time) and am trying to plot the first derivative. However, the graph does not appear to have a simple curve of best fit.
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6cao.png)

I have tried plotting this as a line chart using ggplot's line(), and now wish to plot the slope of each of these line segments as the y value, with the x value being the midpoint of the two times. I have tried lm() as well as diff(x)/diff(y) without any success, and have not found any resources online supporting this problem. Using the lm() function resulted in a line for the entire graph, whereas I wanted the slope of for each line plot. My data frame looks like this:

```
dput(head(ms_data))
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1497554040, 1497554160, 1497554280, 
1497554400, 1497554520, 1497554640), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), V2 = c(0.444, 0.445, 0.445, 0.445, 0.445, 0.445
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And my code looks like this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = ms_data, mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V2))
line <- geom_line()
dot <- geom_point(size = .01)
plot <- plot + line + dot
plot
```

This code all runs, but I don't know how to plot the slope of each individual line segment against the midpoint of the time values.
Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT: A basic example of what I want is this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6cao.png)

Where the green is the original line graph and the blue is the slope of each line segment.

Comment: Instead of posting the results from `head(ms_data)`, post the results of `dput(head(ms_data)`.  Also, when you mean line segments what do you mean?  Can you post or link to an example of what you want?

Comment: Post has been edited and an example is now provided.

Comment: @AndrewFlury Did the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the example of having the blue dots placed in the middle (on the x-axis) of the green line segment. Creating a couple new variables and using them in another `geom_point` call will give you the result. For your example, the slopes are .001 and 0 so this is an odd chart.

```
df <- ms_data %>% 
  arrange(V1) %>% 
  mutate(slope = V2 - lag(V2),
         V3 = V1 - (V1 - lag(V1))/2)

plot <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V2))
line <- geom_line(color = "darkgreen")
dot <- geom_point(size = .01, color = "darkgreen")
plot <- plot + line + dot + geom_point(aes(x = V3, y = slope), color = "blue")
plot
```

[image]